# Should the "naming" and "nomenclature" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have both [naming](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) and [nomenclature](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) - does it make sense to have these as separate tags, or should we merge them? If so, which one would be preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wondered about this before, but as the [naming](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) tag is currently defined, they are not synonyms. The [naming](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) tag is specifically about the process of assigning an identifier to an astronomical object. [nomenclature](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) can be used to talk about any of the technical terms used in astronomy, aside from just those unique identifiers assigned to astronomical objects. If you see the [naming](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) tag used in the wrong way, please help the asker by retagging the question.